# Grant authority to a module to load other modules

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to include the factory pattern in my modules. I have a module `ServiceFactory.js` that looks like this:

```
exports.createService = function(serviceName, paramObj){
  return require('Services/'+serviceName).Service.new(paramObj);
};
```

This module should require other modules (Services) by their names and create an instance. The general `Service.js` lookes like this:

```
const Base = require('base').Base;

exports.Service = Base.extend({
    getName: function(){
        return this.name;
    },
    invoke: function(){
        //do something
    },
});
```

All other Services extend the base Service. I collect all Services in a subfolder "Services" in "lib". When I now use the `createService` method of my factory I get an error like: "Module: ServiceFactory ... has no authority to load Service/..."

Is there a way to grant `ServiceFactory` the authority to load my Services or is there another way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Add-on SDK resolves all requirements when the add-on is packaged, it doesn't happen at run-time. I guess that this is done mostly for performance reasons (modules can be loaded from several locations, searching these location when the extension is running can be slow) but there is a security aspect as well - even if a module is compromised (unintentionally runs code that it got from a web page), it still cannot load any additional modules, in particular not the `chrome` module. But the end result is: you cannot decide dynamically which modules you want to use, you can only load the modules that you explicitly require in your source code.

The work-around in your case would be adding a function that is never called but has all the necessary `require()` calls to make sure that the SDK resolves them:

```js
function dummy()
{
  require("Services/ServiceFoo");
  require("Services/ServiceBar");
  ...
}
```

Having this function in `ServiceFactor.js` will make sure that the `createService()` function can require these modules.

Comment: The other thing to add is that currently, your code can not be properly registered if you use any minification or multiple requires in one line like var a = require('widget'), b = require('chrome'); This is fixed and on track for release https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/pull/738 but it's not currently in the stable release.